# Manipulating String in C#

Tags: c#, string

I have a code in C# and have to print a label with the name of the seller, but i have a problem.
Every line in the label comport 20 letters and i have 2 lines to put this name.

I need to arrange the name of the seller in the 2 lines, without cut words.

For example - Name: JOSE MAURICIO BERTOLOTO MENDES

Line1: JOSE MAURICIO

Line2: BERTOLOTO MENDES

someone know how i do this?
Thanks

---

EDIT: Based in the answers, i implemente this code:

```
string[] SellerPrint = Seller.Split(' ');
Line1 = "";
Line2 = "";
foreach (string name in SellerPrint )
{
     if (Line1.Length <= 20)
     {
          if ((Line1 + name).Length <= 20)
               Line1 += (Line1.Length == 0) ? name : " " + name;
          else
               break;
     }
}
Line2 = (Seller.Replace(Line1, "").Length <= 20) ? Seller.Replace(Line1+ " ", "") : Seller.Replace(Line1+ " ", "").Remove(20);
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: And what if the second line would be > 20 chars?

Comment: James: With the second line would be > 20 chars, i have to cut the extra letters.

Comment: Okay, and if there IS no space in the first 20 characters, what then?  hard-split at 20th regardless?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply split the string into words using `string.Split()` and then add to each as long it small enough to add to the line.

I also wouldn't use the character count but use `Graphics.MeasureString()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can split the full name in to it's individual parts.

```
var names = fullname.Split(' ');
```

Which will give you a string[]. From there you can do the math by looking at length of each string.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is that you want to append all parts of the name until you will reach or exceed your 20 character limit on the next token. When that happens, append a new line with that token and continue appending until you hit the character limit once again.

Here is a quick example:

```
public static string FormatName(string name)
{
    const int MaxLength = 20;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("name");
    if (name.Length <= MaxLength)
        return name;

    string[] tokens = name.Split(' ');
    if (tokens.Length == 0)
        return name; //hyphen the name?

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(name.Length);

    int len = 0;
    foreach (string token in tokens)
    {
        if (token.Length + len < MaxLength)
        {
            sb.Append(token + " ");
            len += token.Length;
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append(Environment.NewLine + token + " ");
            len = 0;
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

**Note**: I left the case open for when a section of the name, without spaces, is longer than 20 characters. Also, this example will continue on to the Nth line, if the name won't fit onto two lines.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the logic.

Use String.split to split the name into an array. Iterate over the strings in the array, concat them into a line, while the line is less than 20 characters. A recursive function would be a good idea! When you are greater than two lines, drop the rest of the names that put it over.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think you can use a special character: '\n' (without the quotes) 
Its basiclly stands for new line. So for example : JOSE MAURICIO BERTOLOTO MENDES will become JOSE MAURICIO \n BERTOLOTO MENDES.